# Commit from subversion to github failed

Tags: git, svn, github, phpstorm

this is my first time collaborating in a project in github. I forked the project to my account https://github.com/Exlord/zf2.

I'm using phpstorm+subversion and successfully checked out the repository to my local windows machine and made the first commit witch was successful
https://github.com/Exlord/zf2/commit/e056a1f97bf6b18dbc0bdf3c82719e315beb47ce

But now when i try to make any commits to the same file or a new file i get this error :

> svn: E160024: Commit failed (details follow): 
>   svn: E160024: Activity already exists 
>   svn: E175002: MKACTIVITY of '/Exlord/zf2/!svn/act/2ed5debc-4601-0010-9024-2b2821a823e4': 409 Conflict (https://github.com)

I tried to update the file and the entire project and it says that all files are up to date.

so anybody know what this error means and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

While you can clone a [GitHub repo with Subversion](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use), and even [commit back](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients#making-commits-to-subversion), it might be easier to use [phpstorm+Git](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-git-integration.html), in order to benefit from a more natural fit between your local repo (which would be a git clone one), and a remote GitHub repo.

Otherwise, as mentioned in "[How do you fix an SVN 409 Conflict Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590355/6309)", mention this to GitHub support as it is mainly an error on the server side.